# Powershell - Workflow is no Running

Tags: workflow, powershell

I created a PowerShell Script in the ISE Editor to Add Sharepoint list items. When I run the script in the ISE the items were added correctly and the workflow (Workflow runs for New Items) is running.

But when I run the script in the PowerShell the Workflow isnt running .....

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the script as admin, with system account? SharePoint prevents the workflows being run from system account.

Comment: I run the script with the farm admin....

Comment: That's the reason. You should run the script by an user which is not in the Farm Administrators group.